# tika default detectors are different for the same code in different apps

Tags: java, apache-tika

The project I'm working on has a WebUI (WAR) that uses Tika, and another application (JAR) that also uses Tika.
Both have the same code:

```
Tika t = new Tika();
String detectedType = t.detect(fileName);
```

Yet each returns a different result.

I used the Tika troubleshooting tips at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#TroubleshootingTika-TroubleshootingApacheTika

In the WebUI I see

```
Tika version: Apache Tika 1.22
Tika detector type org.apache.tika.detect.OverrideDetector
Tika detector type org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector
Tika detector type org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.ZipContainerDetector
Tika detector type org.gagravarr.tika.OggDetector
Tika detector type org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypes
```

In the application I see

```
Tika version: Apache Tika 1.22
Tika detector type org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypes
```

I'm new to Java WARs and JARs, but the project seems to have the correct dependencies,
yet I can't figure out why these two get a different list of default detectors.

Where should I look to find the difference between how these two are using Tika?

Comment: Apache Tika is made up of a few jars, plus a whole bunch of dependencies, make sure they are all included in both places!

Comment: Are these dependencies documented somewhere?  I ran `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, but that copied 150+ JARs. Am I supposed to include all of them?

Building the WAR doesn't directly include most of them, so maybe some are indirectly included.

Comment: If you want to use all of Apache Tika, you need all of the dependencies, yes!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question.

Forgive me if I get some of the Apache Storm terms wrong, I'm new to Storm.

Part of the problem is that I left out what turns out to be a key detail, the JAR in question is being loaded dynamically as part of a Storm worker.

The Storm topology JAR only included a dependency on tika-core, tika-parsers was inadvertently left off.

To solve the problem, I removed the all dependencies on Tika from the topology JAR (they were unnecessary). Now when the JAR in question is loaded, with dependencies on both tika-core and tika-parsers everything is working as expected.